# FTPS via existing SOCKS 5 proxy

Tags: ruby, socks

I am trying to create a Ruby script FTPS connection over SOCKS 5 tunnel, which I've open up via Putty application.

I've successfully test that it works using FileZilla:

[image: filezilla proxy settings]

but having trouble configuring Ruby to use SOCKS connection.

I've tried:

- setting SOCKS server environment variable: `ENV["SOCKS_SERVER"] = "127.0.0.1:9090"`
- Using the Sockify command line: `socksify_ruby localhost 9090 .\gp_mf_ftp.rb""`
- Using `dress-socks` gem: `DressSocks::Socket.new('127.0.0.1', '9090', socks_username: nil, socks_password: nil, socks_server: nil, socks_port: nil, socks_version: '5')`

With no luck- not sure how to troubleshoot next steps.

Running Windows 10; with Ruby 3.1.  Open new ideas I haven't tried yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, using `dress_socks` gem and the following monkeypatch:

```rb
$socks_server = 'x.x.x.x'
$socks_port   = 'xxxx'

#https://github.com/ruby/net-ftp/blob/master/lib/net/ftp.rb#L366
# #monkey patch to use dress socks socket:
class Net::FTP   
  def open_socket(host, port) # :nodoc:
    puts "ignoring passed host: #{host}" unless host.eql?(@host)
    puts "socks5: #{$socks_server}:#{$socks_port}"
    puts "opening socket: #{@host}:#{port}"
    return DressSocks::Socket.new(@host, port, 
      socks_server: $socks_server, socks_port: $socks_port)
  end
end
```

The problem was https://github.com/ruby/net-ftp/blob/332f431b8e15ca26335cb2e75417e7dcbe7d4a5a/lib/net/ftp.rb#L1406

By default the FTP gem looks up the host IP address of the connecting of the connecting socket which is the SOCKS server not the FTP host.  Using the instance variable `@host`  instead of the host value passed in ensures its uses the correct IP address.